# What is the best way to connect an android application and a php server using sockets?

Tags: php, android, sockets

What is the best way to connect an android application and a php server using sockets? I am trying to implement a chat system between multiple clients, but I know that PHP does not allow multithreads.
Sorry for not giving enough information about what I intend to do. I  basically want to create an app simmilar to google latitude, and I also want to implement a chat system between the users. I have aldready decided that I am going to use a MySQl DB and therfore a PHP server so the client communicates with the DB using JSON for data exchange. I am quite new to this and I don't know how the architecture Client-Server-Client communication should look like. I found out that the easiest way to do this is using HTTP requests, but I don't know how I should implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use jabber protocol, install any xmpp server and you can connect to that from android, this is standard for chat applications

Answer (score 0):

use xml-rpc base php webservices for chat server. your chat client will contact to chat server throught web services.

Answer (score 0):

*I was going to make this a comment but I ran out of space, plus it does have some answer-y qualities to it.

1. This question does not contain *nearly* enough information for anyone to usefully help you. How do *you* think it should be done? You can't ask people to critique an idea when you haven't told them what your idea is.
2. PHP is the wrong language for this, because (as you rightly point out) it can't be multi-threaded - amongst a multitude of other reasons. I personally would recommend Node.js (or possibly Java), but that's just my preference.
3. If you still insist on using PHP, [take a look at this](http://thethoughtlab.blogspot.com/2007/04/non-blocking-io-with-php-mio.html). It might give you a point in the right direction for a non-blocking multi-IO setup such as this - but you're letting yourself into a whole world of unnecessary complication by doing this in PHP.